# Change provisioning profile expiration date

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

Is there any way to manually set expiration of provisioning profile. I mean after creating a provisioning profile, I need to expire the profile after two weeks. Is that possible? Also how much is expiration time for ad-hoc provisioning profile?

Comment: there you got your answer, it is not possible, you have to check per code if the app should be opened or not...

Comment: I found that nowadays the expiration time of profile is expiration time of developer account, not 3 months.

Comment: Yes, that rule changed and now the profile has the same expiration date of the developer acc, which is bad.. I think that should be way more flexible.